# Codename one, can't show same BrowserComponent twice

Tags: codenameone

I am facing the following exception:
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Component is already contained in Container: Container...` when I try to show a `Form` that contains a previously initialized (and shown) `BrowserComponent`

I want to re-utilize a `BrowserComponent` so that I skip the load time in subsequent runs (always has same content but has some heavy js)

The code flow can be summarised as follows:

```
BrowserComponent browser;

private void show(){
    Form f = new Form("name", new BorderLayout());
    if(browser == null) // only initialise first time loaded
    {
        browser = new BrowserComponent();
        browser.setURL("jar:///Folder/File.html");
    }
    Container centerBackground = BorderLayout.center(browser); //Exc source
    f.add(CENTER, centerBackground);
    f.show();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving my own issue.

The problem was that I wasn't removing the browser's parent Container before adding it to the layout. The fix consists in adding the following line before creating the `Container`:

```
browser.remove();
```